# apache2.conf how to set a param for a module in based on url parameter

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf

I need to set a param for a module

(specifically is activation of geoencoding module by setting a param GeoIPEnable On)

in httpd.conf based on a parameter in the request url (for example geo=true).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "good" way to do this would be the `<If>` functionality in Apache 2.4.

Assuming that's not available, you're left with rather hackish workarounds.  Assuming the content will be ok with this (this may break if you have dynamic content - can you expand on what's running within Apache?), you could do something along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Do an internal redirect of the requests that have the geoip=true param:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} geoip=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /geoip$1 [PT,QSA,L]

# Make the content under /geoip identical to the docroot:
Alias /geoip /path/to/docroot

# And, configure /geoip for the GeoIP lookups:
<Location /geoip>
    GeoIPEnable On
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

This is a very high traffic server so I dont want to turn rewrite engine on.
Any other way to do it?

Comment: Not without Apache 2.4 - and that's also a runtime evaluation, anyway.  A single rewrite rule is a drop in the bucket of Apache's CPU load - I'd recommend testing the impact instead of ruling out mod_rewrite on principle.